# Java code execution to get result in O(1)

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, concurrenthashmap

I have a webservice from which I gets a time and price. I have saved those records in a ConcurrentHashMap since it needs to support in a multi-threaded environment with timestamp (**LocalDateTime**) as key and price (**BigDecimal**) as the values. The requirement was to get the following details

1. Total records in last 90 records
2. Average records in last 90 records
3. Lowest Price in last 90 records
4. Highest Price in last 90 records
5. Total Price in last 90 records
6. Average Price in last 90 records

I have successfully achieved the requirement by the code a shown below

```
ConcurrentHashMap<LocalDateTime, BigDecimal> data = // my full records

int totalRecords = 0;
BigDecimal highestPrice = new BigDecimal(0.0);
BigDecimal lowestPrice = new BigDecimal(0.0);
BigDecimal totalPriceSum = new BigDecimal(0.0);
Instant currentTime = Instant.now();
Duration limit = Duration.ofSeconds(90);
for (LocalDateTime time : data.keySet()) {
    Duration duration = Duration.between(currentTime , time);
    Boolean matches = ( duration.compareTo(limit) < 0 );
    if(matches) 
    {
        BigDecimal recordPrice = data.get(time);
        if(recordPrice.compareTo(lowestPrice) < 0) {
            lowestPrice = recordPrice;
        }

        if(recordPrice.compareTo(lowestPrice) > 0) {
            highestPrice = recordPrice;
        }
        totalPriceSum = totalPriceSum.add(recordPrice);
        totalRecords++;
    }
}


System.out.println("Total records in last 90 records: "+ totalRecords);
System.out.println("Average records in last 90 records: "+ (totalRecords/90)*100);
System.out.println("Lowest Price in last 90 records: "+ lowestPrice);
System.out.println("Highest Price in last 90 records: "+ highestPrice);
System.out.println("Total Price in last 90 records: "+ totalPriceSum);
System.out.println("Average Price in last 90 records: "+ (totalPriceSum.doubleValue()/90)*100);
```

But my customer says this has some performance issues, and the code should run and give in O(1)

Can anyone please help me or suggest me a different approach to achieve this. Should I not use Collections in order to achieve O(1)

Comment: If this is a webservice, you probably want to have one single service thread/process/app/whatever do your statistics work, writing the data to a persistent, accesible record every 90 seconds, and then have any webservice do _no_ computation whatsoever, instead simply waiting for requests, and when it gets one, access the record, write a response, and go back to waiting for connections.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the reply, actually we dont use persistent storage like DB or anything....they want it to be in cache....and does not need to be persist anywhere

Comment: in last 90 records? .. do you mean  in last 90 seconds?

Comment: @EugenCovaci yes 1min 30 seconds...........that the requirement

Comment: Did you try to use something like a SortedMap? The idea is to stop the iteration on first that doesn't matches the condition. Or maybe to order the KeySet

Comment: @EugenCovaci I choose ConcurrentHashMap which is another type of Hashtable having O(1) in Search, Insertion and Deletion operation http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Instead of using LocalDateTime as the key consider using current system nanos (Long) so the code can quickly calculate the exact keys to iterate over.  I don't see how it could be done in O(1).

Comment: @AndrewS `so the code can quickly calculate the exact keys to iterate over`....I didn't get that....can you show me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments - here's an example of what I meant about calculating the exact keys to use.  It still uses a `LocalDateTime` (instead of a Long for the nanos) as the key, but it is **truncated to seconds**.  So there are at most 90 keys which need to be collected.

There is aggregate `PriceRequest` class to hold concurrent requests within the same second.  (It's not completely thread safe.)

```
public class Last90Seconds {
    private Map<LocalDateTime, PriceRequest> priceRequests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Last90Seconds app = new Last90Seconds();
        app.simulatePriceRequests();  // thread which continuously simulates a price request

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(9000);
            app.reportOnPriceRequests();
        }
    }

    private void simulatePriceRequests() {
        new Thread(new RequestForPriceSimulator()).start();
    }

    private void reportOnPriceRequests() {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        new ReportSimulator().generateReport();
        long elapsedNanos = System.nanoTime() - startNanos;
        System.out.println("Took " + elapsedNanos / 1000.0 + " milliseconds to generate report.\n\n");
    }

    private LocalDateTime truncateToSeconds(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        return ldt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private PriceRequest getPriceTracker(LocalDateTime key) {
        return priceRequests.get(key);
    }

    private PriceRequest getPriceTrackerEvenIfAbsent(LocalDateTime key) {
        return priceRequests.computeIfAbsent(key, v -> new PriceRequest());
    }

    public class RequestForPriceSimulator implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            LocalDateTime rightNow = truncateToSeconds(LocalDateTime.now());
            LocalDateTime ninentySecondsFromNow = rightNow.plusSeconds(90);
            while (rightNow.isBefore(ninentySecondsFromNow)) {

                PriceRequest pt = getPriceTrackerEvenIfAbsent(rightNow);
                double price = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() * 10.0;
                pt.addRequest(price);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                rightNow = truncateToSeconds(LocalDateTime.now());
            }

            System.out.println("All done simulating a price request!\n");
        }
    }

    public class ReportSimulator {

        public void generateReport() {
            double lowest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            double highest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            double total = 0;
            long requestCounter = 0;

            int keyCounter = 0;
            int validKeyCounter = 0;

            LocalDateTime rightNow = truncateToSeconds(LocalDateTime.now());
            LocalDateTime key = rightNow.minusSeconds(90);
            while (key.isBefore(rightNow)) {
                keyCounter++;

                key = key.plusSeconds(1);

                PriceRequest pt = getPriceTracker(key);
                if (pt == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                validKeyCounter++;
                if (pt.getLowest() < lowest) {
                    lowest = pt.getLowest();
                }

                if (pt.getHighest() < highest) {
                    highest = pt.getHighest();
                }

                total += pt.getTotal();
                requestCounter += pt.getCounter();
            }

            System.out.println("Used " + validKeyCounter + " keys out of " + keyCounter + " possible keys.");
            System.out.println("Total records in last 90 seconds: " + requestCounter);
            System.out.println("Average records per second in last 90 seconds: " + requestCounter / 90);
            System.out.println("Lowest Price in last 90 seconds: " + lowest);
            System.out.println("Highest Price in last 90 seconds: " + highest);
            System.out.println("Total Price in last 90 seconds: " + total);
            System.out.println("Average Price in last 90 seconds: " + (total / requestCounter));
        }
    }

    public class PriceRequest {
        private long counter;
        private double lowest;
        private double highest;
        private double total;

        public PriceRequest() {
            lowest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            highest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        public void addRequest(double price) {
            synchronized (this) {

                if (price < lowest) {
                    lowest = price;
                }

                if (price > highest) {
                    highest = price;
                }

                total += price;
                counter++;
            }
        }

        public double getCounter() {
            synchronized (this) {
                return counter;
            }
        }

        public double getLowest() {
            synchronized (this) {
                return lowest;
            }
        }

        public double getHighest() {
            synchronized (this) {
                return highest;
            }
        }

        public double getTotal() {
            synchronized (this) {
                return total;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a lot more records than just the ones for the past 90 seconds. Looping through all of them to filter out only those few that you're interested in is where you're spending most of your time. You need to either

1. Sort the list of keys before you iterate over them (which is not itself a O(1) operation), or
2. Keep the data in sorted order to begin with. (See if [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) fits your needs.)

Once the data is in sorted order, start iterating at the end that is most recent. Once you find a record that is older than 90 seconds, you can stop the loop.

**Note:** This will never truly be O(1), since you're iterating over a list that can change in size. You should still be able to greatly improve performance by ordering the collection you're looping over.

Comment: A third idea might be to remove the old items from the map, while iterating.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I'm assuming that this is only one feature in a bigger system, and that collection of data is being used for other purposes.